# Any Classic ASP gotchas from Win2k3/IIS6 down to Win2k/IIS5?

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6, iis-5

I've got the undoubted joy of having to put a very simple 'classic ASP' internal website on to a Windows 2000 server (which I believe will be running IIS 5).

I won't have access to this server until the weekend, and all of the original development & testing of this website was all done on IIS 6/Windows 2003.

The website is incredibly simple (some ADO database access to SQL Server, basic vbscript and bits of javascript, HTML forms, simple CSS). It's only going to have a shelf-life of a few months (I know we've all heard that one before!) and then both server and software will be upgraded (replaced, in actual fact). It's completely internal to a small local network, there are no external connections to the network, no session or state information being held, no specific user (or SQL Server) accounts etc. In complexity it's barely a 'homework assignment' type website, really.

The server isn't currently doing anything with IIS right now (there's even a fair chance that IIS hasn't actually been installed on it yet), so upgrading or altering IIS on the server would be an option, if it's possible. We could also make minor changes to the ASP code if necessary.

Is there anything I should watch out for? IIS and ASP are not my usual battlegrounds, and unfortunately we don't have the time or budget to bring in a specialist 'just' for this particular job.

Comment: BTW, you might get better answers for this on serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks driis, you're probably right and I did wonder about that. I have a slight (& unfair, unreasonable) fear of serverfault - bizarrely it seems much more technical and less-welcoming (to me) than stackoverflow. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have anything to worry about. A lot of ASP classic applications has been deployed to IIS 5 without a hitch (In fact, I think IIS5 was the de-facto webserver from Microsoft when ASP Classic had the highest adoption).

The only thing I can think of to watch out for, is if the application uses any non-standard or new COM objects, that is not present on the Windows Server 2000 box.

Comment: Thanks again for your reassurance - managed to get some time on the server last night and the website seems to be running okay (thus far!)